# ExcelDataReader Problem with 1252 Encoding

Tags: xamarin, encoding, windows-1252, exceldatareader

I'm just getting started with Xamarin development in Visual Studio 2022 Preview. I'm working on an app that reads Excel or CSV files, for which I have elected to use ExcelDataReader.

Despite following the guidelines to add support for CodePages as per the documentation, I still receive the "NotSupportedException" for 1252 encoding. I have tried lots of approaches but still can't get around this, has anyone seen this and managed to find a solution?

Starting my project from the Xamarin Forms template provided in Visual Studio, I added a page with one button at the top and space for a list of things beneath. The button launches a file picker that allows the user to select their excel file. The filepath is then passed to a data service object that goes about opening and reading the file into a dataset, all goes well until it comes to reading the file. I might that add I have tried .xlsx and .csv files and use Xamarin.Essentials FilePicker to select a file that is stored on my Google Drive (and now locally in the Android Emulator files).

Using Nuget Package manager console I added references to ExcelDatareader, ExcelDataReader.Dataset extension and System.Text.Encoding.CodePages (version 6). This is reflected in the project dependencies.

[image: Project Dependencies folder]

I have added the registration line to the App constructor.

```
public App()
{  
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);                                     
    InitializeComponent();    
    DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
    DependencyService.Register<WasteDataStore>(); // My Data store
    MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

Here's the file reader method within my data store.

```
private async Task<DataSet> ReadXlsx(string filePath)
{
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    
    try
    {
        // Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance); // Uncommenting here has no effect.
        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Fails here with System.NotSupportedException Encoding 1252 data could not be found.
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream, new 
                   ExcelReaderConfiguration(){ FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)}))
            {
                 data = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        { UseHeaderRow = true }});
              }
          }                
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { 
              Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }
      return await Task.FromResult(data);
  }
```

I have tried older versions of ExcelDataReader and CodePages as well as placing the registration line in the ReadXlsx function. i have also tried using "dotnet restore", which runs ok but has no visible effect.

The reason I want to keep ExcelDataReader is because I like the idea of using the AsDataSet feature rather than having to write my own. Any help on this would be great, and thanks in advance.

Comment: "as per the documentation" - please provide links to this, as well as to the project pages for the relevant nuget packages

Comment: Documentation for ExcelDataReader https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader and dotnet project https://dotnet.microsoft.com/

Comment: see https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+android+1252+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks Jason, I hadn't seen any other comments about that setting. working now.

Answer (score 2):

from https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#important-note-on-net-core

To fix, add a dependency to the package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages and then add code to register the code page provider during application initialization

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```